# How to center the app icon in splash screen?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-drawable

I want to set my app icon (located at `@drawable/app_icon.png` at the center bottom of the screen. I've tried the following but it only puts the icon at the bottom left corner.

```
<!-- @drawable/splash_bg.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>

    <item
        android:start="0px"
        android:end="0px"
        android:width="300px"
        android:height="133px"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <bitmap
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo" />

    </item>
    
</layer-list>
```

And also I've tried adding `android:gravity="center"` to the bitmap but it just pixelates the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing android:layout_width="match_parent" and add android:gravity="center"

This is how I create my splash screens

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@drawable/background_splash</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

drawable/background_splash.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!--  Fill the background with a solid color  -->
  <item android:drawable="@color/colorWhite"/>
  <!--  Place your bitmap in the center  -->
<item>
  <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/splash_land"/>
</item>
</layer-list>
```